# Java - BufferedImage to int[] pixels seems corrupted

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have been trying to display an image (`BufferedImage`) using an `int` array for each pixel but every time i pass the array as argument the result is a corrupted image.The image doesnt have `alpha` or `transparent` pixels.

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBHvI.png)

[What it should have displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlkmG.png)

SpriteSheet Class

```
public class SpriteSheet {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int[] pixels;
    BufferedImage image;


public SpriteSheet(String path) {
        image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SpriteSheet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (image == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.width = image.getWidth();
        this.height = image.getHeight();
        pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
    }

}
```

Display Class

```
public class Display {
    private GameWindow displayWin;
    private BufferedImage displayImage;
    public int[] imagePixels;
    private BufferStrategy graphBuffer;
    private SpriteSheet sheet; 
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Display(int width,int height,GameWindow win,SpriteSheet sheet) {
        this.displayImage = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        this.imagePixels = ((DataBufferInt) this.displayImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        this.sheet=sheet;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.displayWin = win;
        this.displayWin.createBufferStrategy(3);
        this.graphBuffer= displayWin.getBufferStrategy();
    }

    public void renderFinal(){
        Level test = new Level(this.sheet, 1);
        test.render(this);
        Graphics g = graphBuffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.drawImage(this.displayImage,0, 0,this.displayImage.getWidth(),this.displayImage.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        graphBuffer.show();
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return this.width;
    }
    public int getHeight(){
        return this.height;
    }
}
```

Level Class

```
public class Level {

    private SpriteSheet levelSheet;
    private int level;

    public Level(SpriteSheet levelSheet,int newLevel) {
        this.levelSheet = levelSheet;
        this.level=newLevel;
    }

    public void render(Display displayLevel){
        if(this.level == 1){
            for (int y = 8; y <280; y++) {
                for (int x=0; x < 230; x++) {
                    displayLevel.imagePixels[x+y*displayLevel.getWidth()]
                            = this.levelSheet.pixels[x+y*displayLevel.getWidth()];
                }
            }
        }        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with the image encoding: color or gray level.

With the BufferedImage, you have two "good" solutions to access the pixels. getRGB() is easy but much slower.

1 - Using the raster, easier because it automatically handles the encoding, but it is slower.

```
WritableRaster r = image.getRaster() ;
for (int y=0, nb=0 ; y < image.getHeight() ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < image.getWidth() ; x++, nb++)
        pixels[nb] = r.getSample(x, y, 0) ; // For a gray level image.
```

2 - Using the DataBuffer, fastest because direct access to the pixels, but YOU have to handle the encoding.

```
switch ( image.getType() )
    {
    case BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY : // Classical gray level images.
        byte[] bb = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
        for (int i=0 ; i < bb.length ; i++)
            pixels[i] = bb[i] & 0xFF ;
        break ;
    }
```

Comment: As for the second solution, by handle the encoding you mean the type of the `BufferedImage`?

Comment: Yes, because the DataBuffer can then be byte, float, int, double and short (so everything), with multiple channels

Answer (score 1):

For example I want to cut an image from 0 to 230 and 8 to 280. This is what you are trying to do it seems. Cut an image part into another image. The images are different size so the widths have to be respected in the transfer as you see, wcxhc to 500x500

I use the following

```
public void test() {
String image=".............";
BufferedImage bim=null;
try {
  bim=ImageIO.read(new File(image));
}
catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("error in b "+ex); }
int wc=bim.getWidth(), hc=bim.getHeight();
int[] pix2=bim.getRGB(0, 0, wc, hc, null, 0, wc);
int[] pix=new int[500*500];
for (int y = 8; y <280; y++) {
            for (int x=0; x < 230; x++) {
                pix[x+y*500]
                        = pix2[x+y*wc];
            }
        }
  BufferedImage bm=new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  bm.setRGB(0, 0, 500, 500, pix, 0, 500);
```

}

}

Comment: I am testing your idea and i'll be back with the results

Comment: Ok, so for now i made it to work with a workaround. I am not using the `pixels` array from `Spritesheet` class but i am passing the image with the coordinates i want to display to `SubImage` function.You were right about the widths but the image is still beign copied in a weird way if i use the arrays. Thanks for the help i am upvoting your answer.